# the post method ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i did this code.there  are two files( index.html and jeu.php) in the first , when i submit a form i will be redirect to the other page(jeu.php) so the problem is in the click event

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Jeu de dammes</title>
</head>
<style>
form { margin-left:500px;margin-top:300px;  width:300px }
  </style>
<body>
<form id="formulaire" style="margin-left:100px, padding: 15px" method="post" >
<table>
<tr><td><h4> The first player</h4></td>
    <td><input   type="text"   id="premier" name="premier"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><h4> The second player</h4></td>
    <td><input   type="text"   id="deuxieme" name="deuxieme"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<button   id="action">Play</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script   src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#formulaire').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var j1 = $('#premier').val();
    var j2 = $('#deuxieme').val();
    if (j1 == "") alert('saisir le nom du premier joueur');
    if (j2 == "") alert('saisir le nom du deuxieme joueur');
    if (j2 != "" && j1 != "") {
    $.post('jeu.php',   {  premier:   j1,   deuxieme:   j2});
     window.location.href = "jeu.php";          
    }
});
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(flower2.jpg)').css('background-size', '100%');
    $("#formulaire").css('background-image', 'url(flower.jpg)');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in another file(jeu.php):

```
<?php
echo $_POST["premier"]."<br/>";
echo $_POST["deuxieme"]."<br/>";
?>
```

the problem :the page jeu.php is always empty

1. why?
2. how can i correct my code?

Comment: By empty you mean that nothing is returned in page source or you don't see anything when you go to this page? Check the page source in your web browser. Second thing is that you send `POST` ajax request to `jeu.php` and immediate after this you redirect browser to the same page but with GET method and without parameters from form. In `jeu.php` your use $_POST array which is always empty when request is GET type.

Comment: the page source is empty AND noting is displayed.how can i correct it

Comment: It's not empty there are two `<br/>`, look in source. To correct this don't use javascript `$(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX, then the jeu.php page will never be "seen"...  What happens is:

1. `index.html` sends data to `jeu.php`, then 
2. `jeu.php` receives that data, does something with it, and returns a response to `index.html`.  Then, 
3. `index.html` does something with the received data -- and this part must be done in the success function of the ajax method in `index.html`.

I suggest that you use the alternate form of the jQuery AJAX method because it is much easier to see how to lay out your code. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jeu.php",
    data: 'premier=' + j1 + '&deuxieme=' + j2,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Server-side response was: ' + data);
    }
});
```

Notes:

1. The above code goes into index.html
2. The response from jeu.php comes back to this structure and is (in this example) alerted in the success function
3. The above code replaces this code:

`$.post('jeu.php',   {  premier:   j1,   deuxieme:   j2});`
`window.location.href = "jeu.php";`

Comment: the values are true in the alert message but the redirection will not work

Comment: i replaced it by `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jeu.php",
    data: 'premier=' + j1 + '&deuxieme=' + j2,
    success: function(data) {
       window.location.href = data.redirect;
  
    }
});` but the page is not found